# How Get-Childitem and only include subfolders and files?

Tags: powershell, file, get-childitem, subdirectory

I have a script, and currently I do the following, which gets the full path to the files in the subdir:

```
$filenameOut = "out.html"

#get current working dir
$cwd = Get-ScriptDirectory 

#get files to display in lists
$temp = Join-Path $cwd "Initial Forms"
$temp = Join-Path $temp "General Forms"
$InitialAppointmentGenArr = Get-ChildItem -Path $temp
```

So this will return a list where the first file in the array looks like this:

```
"//server/group/Creds/Documents/Initial Forms/General Forms/Background Check.pdf"
```

However, to have my generated web page work on our extranet, I can't give the full path to the file.  I just need it to return:

```
"Initial Forms/General Forms/Background Check.pdf"
```

This will be a link I can use on the extranet.  How do I get get-childitem to return just the sub-path?

My script is run from

```
//server/group/Creds/Documents
```

I can't find any examples similar to this.  I'd like to avoid hard-coding the script location as well, in case it gets moved.

Comment: you can't do that. [*grin*] however, you CAN replace the `$CWD` part of the full path with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to simply trim the unneeded path including trailing slash:

```
$filenameOut = "out.html"

#get current working dir
$cwd = Get-ScriptDirectory 

#get files to display in lists
$temp = Join-Path $cwd "Initial Forms"
$temp = Join-Path $temp "General Forms"

$FullPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $temp 
$InitialAppointmentGenArr = $FullPath | %{ $_.FullName.Replace($cwd + "\","")}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Good idea! I had to do this with cwd: $filePath = $file.FullName.Replace($cwd+"\","")

Comment: Updated the answer with the proper path slash.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approch:

```sh
$relativeDirPath = Join-Path 'Initial Forms' 'General Forms'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot/$relativeDirPath | ForEach-Object {
  Join-Path $relativeDirPath $_.Name
}
```

Note that I've used `$PSScriptRoot` in lieu of `$cwd`, as it sound like the latter contains the directory in which your script is located, which automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` directly reports.

Here's a generalized variation that also works with *recursive* use of `Get-ChildItem`:

```sh
$relativeDirPath = Join-Path 'Initial Forms' 'General Forms'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot/$relativeDirPath | ForEach-Object {
  $_.FullName.Substring($PSScriptRoot.Length + 1)
}
```

---

As an aside: In the cross-platform PowerShell (Core) 7+ edition, the underlying .NET Core framework's  `System.IO.Path` type now has a [`.GetRelativePath()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath), which is a convenient way to obtain a relative path from an absolute one, via a reference path:

```sh
# PowerShell (Core) 7+ only.
PS> [IO.Path]::GetRelativePath('/foo/bar', '/foo/bar/bam/baz.txt')
bam/baz.txt
```

Note:

- Since .NET's working directory typically differs from PowerShell's, be sure to provide *full* input paths.
- Also, be sure that the paths are *file-system-native* paths, not based on PowerShell-only drives.
- [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) can be used to determine full, file-system-native paths.